# ООП в JavaScript Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Здравствуйте.

Я недавно узнал, что `JavaScript` в какой-то степени отражает некие объекты и классы. Приемы программирования с использованием объектов очень распространены при написании программ с помощью `Ext JS`. И это делает код более читабельным и легким, если дело идет о большой программе. Там можно создавать объекты, потом переопределять методы в объектах. Все это, как я понял, реализуется при помощи **`Ext.extend()`**; **`Ext.namespase()`**.

Думаю, не только мне было бы очень полезно разобраться в принципах ООП в JavaScript. Английский у меня слишком слабый, чтобы изучать литературу на английском. Пожалуйста, помогите или общим объяснением или дайте ссылку (*на русскоязычную литературу*), где можно узнать подробнее о том, как программировать на `Ext JS` при помощи `namespace`, `extend` и т.д.

**PS**
Ext JS я знаю и то, как использовать этот фреймворк, мне известно. Вопрос состоит в том, как надо программировать, когда речь идет о тысячах строк кода.

Comment: ext3 - это файловая система =) Не тот тег.

Answer (score 2):

http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/31589/ - вот статью можно почитать. Это как раз перевод англоязычной статьи. Еще в конференции extjs@conference.jabber.ru постоянно пребывают два добрых знатока, помогут советами.

Comment: <b>extjs@conference.jabber.ru<b> - это, как я понимаю, электронная почта?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/31589/  - эта статья, в принципе, отвечает на вопрос о том, как сопровождать огромное количество строк кода. А вот все-таки, откуда можно узнать о этих всех принципах наследования, расширения, и т.д. Я просто еще на довольно низкой ступени, google практически не помог (одни английские статьи, которые я хоть и пытался понять, но практически бесполезно).<br>
Спасибо. Статья хорошая.

Comment: Ну или, может как-то коротко можно написать про основные принципы, чтобы был толчек, идея))).

Comment: extjs@conference.jabber.ru - нет, это jabber конференция. Еще на сайте http://examples.extjs.eu/ куча примеров.